# Implementing a LinkedList in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a singly linked LinkedList in Ruby and I'm having some trouble trying to figure out why some of the nodes are disappearing. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head

  def insert(data)
    node = Node.new(data)
    if @head.nil?
      @head = node
    else
      travel = @head
      unless travel.next.nil?
        travel = travel.next
      end
      travel.next = node
    end
    print @head
  end

  def to_string
    result = ""
    travel = @head
    unless travel.nil?
      result << "#{travel.data} => "
      travel = travel.next
    end
    result << "END"
    result
  end

end
```

And here is a call to this class:

```
list = LinkedList.new
list.insert(5)
list.insert(6)
list.insert(7)
```

At the end of insert, I print out `@head` and I can see that all three nodes are in the list. However, when I make a separate call to `to_string`, `@head` only has the first node but everything else is gone. Can anyone point me in the right direction to what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this could help ? http://matt.weppler.me/2013/08/14/implementing-a-linked-list-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with the keyword `unless`. In ruby, it is a conditional statement, just like `if`. It is not a loop. Just replace them with the keyword `until`.

About the linked list in general, the point of it is to make insertion in O(1), whereas you are doing it in O(n) (traverse the list and insert the node at the end). Instead, you can just insert the new node at the beginning, it will be ok.

Finally, ruby's convention is to name the to_string method `to_s`, so it will be called when printing the list.

Also, you have the possibility of making `Node` an internal class of `LinkedList`. It will be useful if you want to implement other node-based data structures (deque, ring, tree, etc)

Comment: Thank you! I'll make the changes.